# How to test an alert for hourly?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm quite new to prometheus, I have an alert with `for: 1h` I would like to know what should be the eval_time set when testing for alerts? 
currently it fails, and works only if the alert: 1m and eval_time: 10m

Please someone explain me how this works!

example:

```
groups:
- name: spark.rules
  rules:
  ##### ALERTS #####
  - alert: xxxSparkJobsNotConsuming
    expr: rate(foo{data_type="bar"}[5m]) == 0
    for: 1h ---> works if i set it to 5m
    labels:
      service: spark
      severity: warning
      source: spark
    annotations:
      description: 'Nothing have been consumed for 1 hour.'
```

Tests:

```
   rule_files:
      - spark.rules.yml
    evaluation_interval: 1m

    tests:
     - interval: 1m
       input_series:
        - series: 'foo{data_type="bar"}'
          values: '0'
        - series: 'foo{data_type="bar"}'
          values: '64706+0x10'
       alert_rule_test:
        - eval_time: 2h
          alertname: xxxSparkJobsNotConsuming
          exp_alerts:
           - exp_labels:
               data_type: xxxx
               service: spark
               severity: warning
               source: spark
             exp_annotations:
               description: 'Nothing have been consumed for 1 hour.'
       promql_expr_test:
        - expr: 'foo'
          eval_time: 4m
          exp_samples:
            - labels: 'foo{data_type="bar"}'
              value: 64706
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You use both `"xx"`, `"xxx"` and `"xxxx"` for the value of `data_type` across your message, so I'm not sure what's what. Maybe next time try to use `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"baz"`. Or `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`. In particular, both of the `input_series` you define have the exact same name and label values. I will assume that's not the case in your actual test, and I'll call them `series1` and `series2`.]

Now, leaving that aside, your test defines 2 time series, with samples 1 minute apart:

```
series1: 0
series2: 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706 64706
```

`series1` has just the one sample, meaning your alert, that uses `rate` will never trigger on it, since `rate` needs at least 2 samples to produce a result.

`series2` has a constant value of 64706 for 11 minutes, meaning the `rate(series2[5m]) == 0` expression in your alert will hold between minutes 1 (the first time you have 2 samples in your `5m` range) and 15 (the last time when the `5m` range contains 2 samples). Meaning that your alert will fire for 14 minutes (or during a successive 15 minutes, not sure which definition `for: X` uses).

In other words, any value of `for: X` up to 14m (or 15m) will result in your alert firing at one time or another. Any value larger than that will result in the alert never firing, because the condition never holds for that long. (That being said, the `alert_rule_test` has `eval_time: 2h`, which I take to mean "the alert must be firing at `2h` from the start" and that should never be the case, regardless of what value you use in `for:`.)

Anyway, the point is that you need `series2` to cover at least as much as `for:` in order for that condition to hold. If you have 10 minutes worth of samples, the condition cannot hold for 2 hours (unless, of course, the condition is that there are no recent samples).

I don't know what to say about `eval_time: 2h`, I guess you'll just have to play around with it and see why it doesn't appear to do what it says on the tin.

Comment: so you mean to say we can never test an alert if the for condition is 1h even i have values for 1h?

Comment: No, I meant to say that you need to have samples for `1h` if you're going to test an alert with `for: 1h`. As is, you only appear to have 10 minutes worth of samples.